# How to clone react project via browser

Tags: reactjs

I am using **React** to render my page.

I am wondering if it is possible to convert my `html` back to `jsx` code from browser perspective? Actually I want to clone my project folder from browser.

[image]

For example, this is my react code.

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my browser, I can only see the html file only in inspector.

I tried to check on resource on chrome to see if there is something similar to my react project folder. But there is no exact same things

Is there a way to do this purpose?

[image]

----------updated , by using developer tool->source

I have tried to use developer tool to inspect some react js code. But the code is nothing like usual react js code. (I dont know how to call this code below, but it is weird)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the intentions are (whether debugging or something else), but there are a couple of ways that you could see the React (JSX) code. One would be through the dev tools if you open up the `Sources` tab there you can see the whole App structure like so: [image]

Another way is to install the React dev tools plugin for browsers from https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html#installation

Comment: It is just that I want to analyse the code from other website, which I knew they are developed in react js.  For example, I want to see how the logic is like within that components.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your screencap, But when I open up the index file via browser, mine is nothing like the usual js code. Do I need some more plugin to convert the code?

Comment: If you can't see it then most probably the web app has its source map disabled and you can't get the source code, only bundled js is delivered on frontend. Try looking on the source tab for some other website.

Comment: oh, bundled js means a script that is converted by babel already? may I know how can I do the same things for my website, if I also want